# Ruby file encoding behaves differently when from the shell vs as a cronjob

Tags: ruby, cron

I have a Ruby script that creates a string and writes to a file. When I run it from my shell, it works fine. When I run it as a cronjob, when I try to write to the file I get the error `invalid byte sequence is US-ASCII`. The same version of Ruby is being used when I run it either way. Why would this happen?

Comment: Compare your environment variables b/n your shell and cron.  My guess is that in one you're setting LANG or one of the other encoding variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of a string that ends up in a file is determined by **Encoding.default_external**.

Unless you set it explicitly, the default_external encoding is determined by your environment.

So, your two different environments must have different settings.  You can determine the local settings on the command line by looking at the output of:

```
$ echo $LC_CTYPE (blank on OSX)
```

or:

```
$ echo $LANG
```

And you can determine the default_external encoding in a ruby program by doing this:

```
puts Encoding.default_external.name
```

I would add that line to your ruby program, then run your code in each environment and examine the output.

To override the environment's settings, you can explicitly set the default_encoding in your program:

```
Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"
```

Or, a more surgically precise approach is to set the external encoding of a file when you open the file:

```
File.open('output.txt', 'w:UTF-8') do |f|
   ...
end
```